# How do I specify default values for gradle custom task inputs

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I've got a custom gradle task that looks a bit like this:

```
task foo(type:FooTask) {
    in file('foo.in')
    out file('foo.out')
}

class FooTask extends DefaultTask {
    @InputFile
    File in

    @OutputFile
    File out

    @TaskAction
    def doTheFoo() {
         // Do stuff with in and write to out
    }
}
```

This is great, but 99% of the time the output of FooTask should be written to `"$buildDir/foo.out"`.  I'm told gradle is big on using convention to minimize the size of scripts; how do I make this the default value so that my tasks don't have to define it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply set it on the instance variable or in a constructor.

```
@InputFile
File in = project.file("${project.buildDir}/foo.out")
```

Comment: That's what I initially thought, but how can the `project` property be available at that time? Isn't it set after the Task instance has been created?

Comment: The property is available because it is set in the superclass's constructor.